# What does it mean by "Fast script call and stripping" in programming

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Hi I am currently developing App for iOS on Unity3D and I am optimizing my code. I found a term that I am not quite sure I understand, which is found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimisation.html), "Fast script call and stripping may lead to random crashes on iOS. Try without them", the last sentence.

From what I understand is fast enable/disable or turn on/off some gameObject in the game scene. Is that what it's trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand is fast enable/disable or turn on/off some
>   gameObject in the game scene. Is that what it's trying to say?

**No.**

***Fast script call*** is when you set `Script Call Optimization` to `Fast but no Exceptions` in the Build Settings. When you do this, exception will be disabled in your app. There will be no array bound checking and other checking that prevents crash thus making your app run fast. *This is done to increase the speed of your app*.

The bad side to this is that if something goes wrong, your app will just crash.

***Stripping*** is a method of removing classes and functions that are not referenced in your project.You can enable this by checking **Strip Engine Code*** in the Build Settings. *This is done to reduce the size of your app*. There are many other type of stripping. You can learn more about them [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html).

Comment: Thanks for ur clean answer, that is exactly what I am asking. Thanks!